# Como obter o valor de uma lista de UF através da consulta de CEP via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário de endereço onde o usuário digita o CEP e automaticamente é preenchido outros campos, via Ajax . O problema é que não consigo obter o valor da UF, que no meu caso é uma lista.

meu código exemplo:

```
  <fieldset>
<legend>Endereco:</legend>

    @Html.Label("Cep: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.CEP, new { maxlength = "9", id = "Cep", name = "Cep", })       
<br/> 

    @Html.Label("Endereco: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.DescricaoEndereco, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Endereco", name = "Endereco" })

    <br />
    @Html.Label("Número: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Numero, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Numero" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Complemento: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Complemento, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Complemento" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Logradouro: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Logradouro, new { maxlength = "5", id = "Logradouro" })
    <br />

    @Html.Label("Bairro: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Bairro, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Bairro", name = "Bairro" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Cidade: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Cidade, new { maxlength = "40", id = "Cidade", name = "Cidade" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("UF: ")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.UF, Model.UFList, new { id = "UF",name="UF" })
```

Código javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#zipcode").blur(function () {

        consulta = $("#zipcode").val()
        consulta = consulta.replace("-", "");

        var url = "http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/" + consulta + ".json";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                $("#street").val(json.logradouro)
                $("#district").val(json.bairro)
                $("#city").val(json.localidade)
                $("UF").val(json.UF)
                switch (json.UF) {
                    case "AC":
                        $("#UF").val("Acre")
                        break;
                    case "AL":
                        $("#UF").val("Alagoas")
                        break;
                    case "AP":
                        $("#UF").val("Amapá")
                        break;
                    case "AM":
                        $("#UF").val("Amazonas")
                        break;
                    case "BA":
                        $("#UF").val("Bahia")
                        break;

                    case "CE":
                        $("#UF").val("Ceará")
                        break;
                    case "DF":
                        $("#UF").val("Distrito Federal")
                        break;
                    case "ES":
                        $("#UF").val("Espírito Santo")
                        break;
                    case "GO":
                        $("#UF").val("Goiás")
                        break;
                    case "MA":
                        $("#UF").val("Maranhão")
                        break
                    case "MT":
                        $("#UF").val("Mato Grosso")
                        break;
                    case "MS":
                        $("#UF").val("Mato Grosso do Sul")
                        break;
                    case "MG":
                        $("#UF").val("Minas Gerais")
                        break;
                    case "PA":
                        $("#UF").val("Pará")
                        break;
                    case "PB":
                        $("#UF").val("Paraíba")
                        break;
                    case "PR":
                        $("#UF").val("Paraná")
                        break;
                    case "PE":
                        $("#UF").val("Pernambuco")
                        break;
                    case "PI":
                        $("#UF").val("Piauí")
                        break;
                    case "RJ":
                        $("#UF").val("Rio de Janeiro")
                        break;
                    case "RN":
                        $("#UF").val("Rio Grande do Norte")
                        break;
                    case "RS":
                        $("#UF").val("Rio Grande do Sul")
                        break;
                    case "RO":
                        $("#UF").val("Rondônia")
                        break;
                    case "SC":
                        $("#UF").val("Santa Catarina")
                        break;
                    case "RR":
                        $("#UF").val("Roraima")
                        break;
                    case "SP":
                        $("#UF").val("São Paulo")
                        break;
                    case "SE":
                        $("#UF").val("Sergipe")
                        break;
                    case "TO":
                        $("#UF").val("Tocantins")
                        break;

                    default:
                        $("#UF").val("")
                }

            },
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Por acaso você não teria um erro nesse selector aqui: `$("UF").val(json.UF)`? Além do mais eu não entendi exatamente o seu problema, pode explicar um pouco melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parceiro, como seu campo de Estado é uma lista, você não pode usar o .val(), você precisará SELECIONAR um item da sua lista.
Tente o seguinte:

Troque todo o seu switch case pela linha abaixo:

```
$("#UF option[value='"+json.UF+"']").attr("selected", true);
```

--
Eu particularmente não gosto muito do $.ajax(), prefiro usar o:

```
$.getJSON( "url.php", function(data){});
```

com isso eu consigo tratar o retorno. Mas você pode usar os métodos .done(), .error() e .fail() do $.ajax(). Então se não cair no success, vem pro error ou fail.

Comment: Obrigado Deu certo!!

Comment: Funcionou certinho?

Comment: sim! só mais uma coisinha parceiro. quando envio um CEP invalido ele mi retorna = correiocontrolcep({"erro":true}); gostaria de montar uma condição com um alert para o usuario, nao consigo manipular o erro e colocar em alguma variavel para poder desenvolver!

Comment: Editei minha resposta

Comment: OBG!!! Obtive Sucesso!!!

Comment: Que solução usou? $.getjson() ou os outros?

Comment: Deu certo valeu pela força!!